# What's wrong with my JQuery selectors?

Tags: jquery, html

I know I'm doing something unbelievably dumb, but for the life of me I cannot see it. Why isn't the "delete" link displaying on mouseover?

http://jsfiddle.net/LkAVz/

JS

```
$('p.thumbnail').hover(function(){
    $('this').children('a.delete').show();
}, function() {
    $('this').children('a.delete').hide();
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="image">
    <p class="thumbnail">
        <img src="#" alt="" />
        <a class="delete" href="id=4&amp;image=1" style="display:none">Delete image</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Please, someone put me out of my misery. Thanks!

Comment: `$(this)` not `$('this')`

Comment: To give you an understanding why, `$('this')` in quotations will try to select a HTML Tag of `<this></this>` =)

Comment: Also use `toggle()` if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to select `<this>` tags with `$('this')` remove the quotes to select the current element.

```
$('p.thumbnail').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('a.delete').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).children('a.delete').hide();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LkAVz/1/).

Comment: \*faceplam\* Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh! Thank you! I just couldn't see it. So stupidly obvious. #oneofthosedays